# How to add Ivy to Ant dynamically

Tags: java, ant, ivy, build.xml

Typically, to make Ivy tasks available to an Ant build, you need to:

1. Add `ivy.jar` to `${ANT_HOME}/lib`.
2. Add an `xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"` declaration to your build.xml's `<project>` element.
3. Add a `<taskdef>` declaration inside build.xml that reference's the `ivy.jar`'s `antlib.xml` file where all other tasks are defined.

I'd like to accomplish all of the above **except** the first step (adding `ivy.jar` to `${ANT_HOME}/lib`). I'd like to have `ivy.jar` living somewhere inside my project, say, at `lib/buildtime/ivy.jar`, and somehow reference `lib/buildtime/ivy.jar` as where Ivy is located.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The taskdef (step 3) is not required if the ivy jar is located in a standard ANT library directory.

I would recommend including a special "bootstrap" target that will install the ivy jar. Once this is done all other dependencies (including 3rd party ANT tasks) can be downloaded by ivy as a build dependency.

Here is my default build file that demonstrates the concept:

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="bootstrap" description="Install ivy">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='build/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The "bootstrap" target only needs to be run once on a new development environment. Once installed the ivy jar is available to all future ANT runs.
- This example doesn't use "$ANT_HOME/lib" (which you may not have write permissions for). Instead it uses the lesser known "$HOME/.ant/lib" directory which serves the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Mark O'Connor (+1) - 2 quick followups: (1) what is the `$HOME` variable (as opposed to `$ANT_HOME`)? And (2) Do I *have* to use `$HOME/.ant/lib`? Why couldn't I just place `ivy.jar` (once fetched/`get`ted from Maven) inside, say, `lib/buildtime`? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja The $HOME variable on Linux is the environment variable that points at the user's home directory. In Java it's the "user.home" property which is what is used in the example above. You don't have to put the jar in this location. The real advantage of doing so is that you then don't required a taskdef to load ivy. In my opinion it's a lot simpler and means all builds on that machine are ivy enabled, which is what I want. Everything else is build specific and downloaded using ivy.

Comment: This worked great for me using IntelliJ IDEA 13 on Windows 7. I did have to "Invalidate Caches" from the IDEA File menu in order to get the Ant autocomplete for Ivy actions working.