# Manually retrieving Ivy dependencies as locally unmanaged libs in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I have a pattern in Java/Ant where I use Ivy to fetch my dependencies in a task and put them in a local lib/ folder of the project. I do not want to have a local Maven and I only expect developers to run the dependency updater when they change something (I commit the libs in lib/ after they've been fetched).

How can I leverage the SBT dependency settings to fetch them to a local lib/ folder manually and be used as "unmanaged" dependencies (as opposed to lib_managed)? I don't really want to force the developer to set his ivy.home or build a launcher configuration. I'd rather just have a task that is callable that fetches the libs to where I specify in the build.sbt/scala. Any examples of this being done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sbt, but and approach I take with ANT is to create a bootstrap target that sets up a developer's machine, so that ivy can be used to manage dependencies. Take a look at the following example:

- [How to add Ivy to Ant dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947753/how-to-add-ivy-to-ant-dynamically/16949496#16949496)

Comment: That is a pattern I already have, I want to use sbt directly w/out a build.xml separate

Answer (score 0):

Managed can't be translated to unmanaged in general.  There are special cases where some jars can be put in `lib/` with equivalent resulting behavior, but not generally.  Examples of problems:

1. plugins can request jars to be downloaded in custom configurations and unmanaged wouldn't cover those
2. each classpath/configuration requires a separate directory containing all jars
3. unmanaged dependencies lose the associated metadata, which is used by `doc` to link to external sites automatically, for example

This is a general problem with existing dependency management solutions for Java (Maven/Ivy).  It is possible to approximate the idea of locked, offline resolution, but not especially cleanly, easily, or flexibly.  (I'm aware of Ivy's `retrieve`.)  In sbt, it probably requires using `lib_managed/`, `skip in update := true`, `offline := true`, and keeping the `update` cache around (in `target/`), but this isn't documented or tested.

(For a longer-term direction, [Adept](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adept-dev) has locking down dependencies and offline usage as a core goal.)